# Collect into Multimap with order preserved

Tags: java, java-stream, multimap

I have a list of attributes like `attr1`, `attr2`, etc. I also have a function that takes an attribute and returns a list of prefixes.

```
private List<String> getAttributePrefixes(String attribute) {
 //get prefix for attribute
}
```

I want to create a map whose key is the prefix and value is the attribute. Since the prefix could be repeated, I want to output the result as a multimap.

So, for the example above, the output Multimap will look like:

```
{ 
  a = [attr1, attr2],
  at = [attr1, attr2],
  att = [attr1, attr2],
  attr = [attr1, attr2],
  attr1 = [attr1],
  attr2 = [attr2]
}
```

The problem I have with my code is that the order is not preserved. For example, the entries in my map look like this:

```java
a = attr2, attr1 (I call getAttributePrefixes function first for attr1 and then attr2)
```

I want `attr1` to come first and then `attr2`. Here's my code:

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = attributes.stream()
                                              .map(attribute -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(attribute, getAttributePrefixes(attribute)))
                                              .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                                                                     .stream()
                                .map(prefix -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(prefix, entry.getKey())))
                                                      .collect(ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) rather than a map structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `stream` usually gives no to little ordering guarantees as it was created with a parallel execution in mind. One simple option is to try out [`jOOλ`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) as a drop-in replacement that was implemented for single threaded execution. It also has a nice `groupBy` method for your use case.

If that is not an option/working, you have to perform the grouping manually to get your ordering.

```
    Map<String, List<String>> multimap = attributes.stream()
        .map(attribute -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(attribute, getAttributePrefixes(attribute)))
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
            .stream()
            .map(prefix -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(prefix, entry.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

`groupingBy` is a non-parallel collector so it should work. You'd need to wrap the given map into a multimap though.